# Integration through Substitution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let me explain my problem with a typical example:

$\int2x\cdot \sin(x^2)$ What we typically would do is write $u=x^2$ therefore $du=2xdx$ so our integral would be $$\int2x\sin(u)\cdot \frac{du}{2x}=\int \sin(u)du$$ the rest is trivial. My problem or difficulty would why is $2x$ not primarily affected by the substitution, so why don't we re-write it as $\sqrt u$ and let it cancel by the differential?

Comment: With $u = x^2$ (so that $x = \sqrt{u}$), and by the abuse of notation $$\mathrm{d}u = 2x\,\mathrm{d}x \implies \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}},$$ you could write
$$ \int 2x\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int 2\sqrt{u} \sin(u) \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}. $$  This is precisely the same integral, arrived at via a slightly different  set of algebraic manipulations.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you rewrote $2x$ as $2\sqrt{u}$, it would still cancel out. Hence, it doesn't really affect the outcome of the integration. I hope that answers your question.

$$\int 2\sqrt{u}\sin(u)\cdot \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}=\int \sin(u)du=-\cos(x^2)+ C $$

Comment: you'd have to use partial integration

Comment: Not really. You get the same outcome as above. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: John perfect, yeah now i got what you mean. I would have to substitute it twice and forgot to substitute in the frac

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking exactly. The idea in substitution is to substitute all $x$-terms by equivalent $u$-terms and then hopefully get a simpler integral.

In your case, if $u = x^2$ then $du = 2xdx$, so
$$
\int 2x \sin\left(x^2\right)dx
 = \int \sin\left(x^2\right) \cdot 2x dx
 = \int \sin(u) du,
$$
and nothing needs to be canceled.

Comment: You start with the statement that you aren't sure if you are answering the question.  In such cases, *please* use the comments below the question in order to ask for clarification.  Please do not answer the question until you are sure that you understand what is being asked.

Comment: @XanderHenderson oknp - added an answer since it seemed like a decent guess that will be helpful for others if not for op -- but happy to convert to a comment if you like, please let me know